# Como importar dados do mysql com VBA sem desconfigurar o texto

Tags: mysql, vba

Tenho uma macro que conecta ao mysql e executa uma query que esta em arquivo de texto e adiciona os registros em uma planilha de excel. Ocorre que o texto vem desconfigurado. Exemplo:
Correto: QTDE DE CHAMADAS REALIZADAS (VISÃO CPF)
Como vem: QTDE DE CHAMADAS REALIZADAS (VISÃƒO CPF)

Como configuro e onde para que a query me traga os resultados sem os problemas com texto?

Procedure de conexão:

```html
Sub Conexao(SQL)

    On Error GoTo Error


    Set myCon = New ADODB.Connection
    myCon.ConnectionString = _
    "driver={mysql odbc 5.2 Unicode Driver};" & _
    "server=172.17.0.140;database=DWH_RBZ;uid=usuario;pwd=senha;Option=3;"
    myCon.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    myCon.Open

    
    With myCmd
          Set .ActiveConnection = myCon
          .CommandType = adCmdText
          .CommandText = SQL
    End With
    
    With myRS
       .LockType = adLockPessimistic
       .CursorType = adOpenKeyset
       .CursorLocation = adUseClient
       .Open myCmd
    End With

    Exit Sub

Error:
    MsgBox Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description, vbExclamation, "ERRO DE CONEXAO COM O BANCO"
    

End Sub
```

Procedimento que cola os dados da query na planilha

```html
Sub Roda_Query_1()
Dim SQL As String
Dim dias As Integer

    dias = CDate(Dt_Final) - CDate(Dt_Incio)
    For i = 0 To dias
        SQL = LinhaALinhaLer
        SQL = Mid(SQL, 4, 1000000)
        SQL = Replace(SQL, "(@inicio)", "('" & Format(Dt_Incio, "yyyy-mm-dd") & " 00:00:00')")
        SQL = Replace(SQL, "(@fim)", "('" & Format(Dt_Final, "yyyy-mm-dd") & " 23:59:59')")
        
        Conexao (SQL)
        
        If myRS.RecordCount = 0 Then
            MsgBox ("Erro na consulta do relatório")
            myRS.Close
            myCon.Close
            Exit Sub
        End If
        
        
        If VerificaExistePlan("Produtividade") = False Then
           Call Cria_Plan_Dados
        End If
        Sheets("Dados").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset myRS
    Next i



    myRS.Close
    myCon.Close
   End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Creio que se definir o **Charset** para a conexão irá resolver o problema.

```
myCon.Charset = "utf-8"
```

Verifique também o Charset da tabela. Poderá testar também utilizando o driver **ANSI** ao invés do **Unicode** utilizado.

Espero ter ajudar, qualquer coisa poste um feedback que testaremos com mais tempo para achar a solução.